# Can Chrome and Firefox transfer a browsing session?

Tags: windows-7, mac, firefox, google-chrome

I'd like to be able to transfer a browsing session from **Firefox 3 on my Mac** to **Chrome on my Windows 7 Netbook**.

It seemed that TabCloud might be the answer, but it currently doesn't work with Firefox 3. I can't find any other extensions that will let me transfer a set of tabs between these two browsers. (Running Chrome on the mac isn't an option, as it's an iMac G5.)

I'm fairly sure using Firefox Sync isn't an option, as that'll only work with other installations of Firefox. (I don't think that FF is a very good netbook browser... yet.) Can anyone think of a solution to this?

Comment: did xmarks do it for you?

Comment: @pootzko - Yep, it did the job!

Comment: @pootsko... bus see below.

Comment: see bellow ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) is the right solution for you. It is a cross-browser plugin and it supports tab, bookmark, password synchronisation over different browsers (even under different OS's).

Comment: This works amazingly well. Unfortunately, after installing xmarks om all of my computers, I found out [that it's shutting down in January](http://lifehacker.com/5649435/xmarks-bookmark-syncing-shutting-down-in-january-2011), so I'll need another solution.

Comment: it's not shutting down, lastpass bought them, and xmarks will live on. take a look here - http://blog.xmarks.com/?p=2033 (dec 2nd)